# copydir in ant script

Tags: java, ant

By using following ant script all the files will be copied from source.dir to build.dir

```
<target name="compile" description="">
        <copy todir="${build.dir}">                                          
            <fileset dir="${source.dir}"/>
        </copy>
    </target>
```

means:

```
source/
  1.html
  2.html
  html/
   3.html
   4.html

build/
  1.html
  2.html
  html/
   3.html
   4.html
```

I want the following

```
source/
  1.html
  2.html
  html/
   3.html
   4.html

build/
  1.html
  2.html     
  3.html
  4.html
```

Can anyone help me out here, i am new in ant script!

Comment: And how can i apply filtering in Copydir ?

Comment: So you want to create a directory structure in the target directory where there wasn't one in the source directory? What are the criteria to decide which files go in which target subdirectory? Or do you have source and target reversed in the question (in which case you just need a "flatten mapper")?

Comment: i have made few changes, please have a look

Comment: all the *.html files in source directory should be copied to build directory, but there can be sub directories inside source but not within build directory.

Comment: That makes much more sense, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to manipulate the file names as you copy, copy you need a [mapper](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/mapper.html)

```
    <copy todir="${build.dir}">                                          
        <fileset dir="${source.dir}"/>
        <flattenmapper/>
    </copy>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [Ant Move Tag](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/move.html)

Here is an example..

```
<move file="file.orig" todir="dir/to/move/to"/>
```

For multiple files ...

```
  <move todir="some/new/dir">
    <filelist dir="my/src/dir">
      <file name="file1.txt"/>
      <file name="file2.txt"/>
    </filelist>
  </move>
```